# Canvas get ref element

Tags: reactjs, canvas

I want to get a canvas element, defined in react.render() and I tried to use ref instead of id, but I always get back a NULL element. What am I doing wrong here?
document.getElementById('canvas1') seems also not to work, that's why I tried this.refs.refName, but without success.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './../css/index.css'


class App extends React.Component {


   constructor(props){
      super(props)      
      this.SetImage();

      window.a = this.state
   }


   SetImage() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg';
    var canvas = this.refs.cavas1; //Gives always a NULL element
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function() {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      img.style.display = 'none';
    };
    var color = this.refs.color1;//document.getElementById('color');
    function pick(event) {
      var x = event.layerX;
      var y = event.layerY;
      var pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
      var data = pixel.data;
      var rgba = 'rgba(' + data[0] + ', ' + data[1] +
                 ', ' + data[2] + ', ' + (data[3] / 255) + ')';
      color.style.background =  rgba;
      color.textContent = rgba;
    }
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', pick);
   }


   render(){
      return (
         <div className="main-container">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>

            <canvas id="canvas1" ref="canvas1" width="100" height="100" styles="float:left"></canvas>
            <div id="color1" ref="color1" styles="width:200px;height:50px;float:left"></div>
         </div>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <App />,
   document.querySelector('#root')
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that because you are trying to get reference to canvas from constructor:

```
  this.SetImage();
```

At that point the render method hasn't been run so the canvas isn't there. Put the code to get handle of canvas in `componentDidMount`.

Also I think the ref API you use is a bit old, use more modern [approach](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Ok, now canvas is not NULL anymore, but undefined. What does undefined differ from NULL?

Comment: @HansPeterLoft Did you look into link provided in answer? also then show your new code.

Comment: I got it, i just used your modern approach: ref={(ref) => this.canvas1 = ref}, thank you.